# Where should you apply transformations when extending Android ImageView's?

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-image

I'm making a custom component which extends ImageView on Android. The components function is fairly complicated - to always fill the height of its container by scaling but to trim empty space on the width. It will also automatically apply a 90 degree rotation transformation if the width is bigger than the height, before applying any scaling.

I know how to do these transformations and have output their results to file so I know they work correctly. What I don't know is where/what methods to do this in when extending the View.

I'm not including the transformation code for now because it doesn't seem relevant but below shows where I call these transformations currently

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    if (!mConversionComplete) {
        applyTransformations(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }
    Drawable imageDrawable = getDrawable();
    if (imageDrawable != null) {
        int height = MeasureSpec.getSize(MeasureSpec.AT_MOST);
        int width = (int) Math.ceil((float) height * (float)     imageDrawable.getIntrinsicWidth() / (float) imageDrawable.getIntrinsicHeight());
        setMeasuredDimension(width, height);
    } else {
        super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
    }
}
```

I am currently doing the transformations from onMeasure as I need to be able to use the measure specs (below). I record whether I have handled the transformations so that I only do them once, but I think there's probably a 'right' place to do this which isn't onMeasure

```
int targetHeight = MeasureSpec.getSize(heightMeasureSpec);
int targetWidth = MeasureSpec.getSize(widthMeasureSpec);
```

Comment: Have you read over the Custom View [tutorial](http://developer.android.com/training/custom-views/index.html)?

Comment: Hey, yes and tried to apply transformations in onDraw but with no luck. The tutorial is what made me think onMeasure could be right, but the implementation felt hacky to me so I thought I'd consult some of the people here

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your description of your customization you should limit your scope to determining the dimensions of the ImageView and using [setImageMatrix](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.html#setImageMatrix%28android.graphics.Matrix%29). Let the android system do the *hard* work for you.

Comment: Thanks, that was my first attempt, but because I'm trying to preRotate and then postScale (with the height and width now effectively reversed) it dies because it tries to create a bitmap

Comment: What do you mean by "dies", post `logcat` log if applicable.

Comment: Width is say 1k and height 500; I've rotated and now they are the opposite; a bitmap is created with height 100 and the matrix applied...  Log cat gives an error like 'y + height must be >= bounds' I'll post the exact message and matrix when I'm at my machine tomorrow